# Rally: How do I access custom created fields via the Web Services API

Tags: ruby, rally

I have read through the Web Services site at http://developer.rallydev.com/help/

The basic issue I have is that I am trying to update custom created fields in Rally from a Ruby script and I do not know the format to use. The Rally Devs said this was possible and directed me to post here as they do not support users with such things.

I am wondering if anyone else has been able to do this.  I can get the defect, but the debug info has not given me any clues as to where these custom fields may be lurking.  Thanks in advance for your help and please let me know if you need any additional information.  The simple code I have right now is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'rally_rest_api'

defect = "DE677"
logger = Logger.new("debug-rally.txt")
logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

rally = RallyRestAPI.new(:username => "hidden",
                     :password => "hidden",
                     :logger   => logger,
                     :version  => 1.34)
result = rally.find(:defect) { equal :formattedid, defect }

if result.page_length == 0
  puts "The defect "+defect+" was not found"
elsif result.page_length == 1
  puts "Found it"
  res_array = result.results
  thedefect = res_array.at(0)
  puts thedefect.state
  puts thedefect.requirement.defects
else
  puts "Returned more than one result"
  puts result.page_length
  res_array = result.results
  for i in res_array
    puts i
  end
end
```

EDIT:It was actually staring me right in the face.  When I checked the debug log again they were in the xml. For instance in the UI there was a custom field called fu and in the resulting xml it was there as bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a display name and a name property when you create it. In your example my guess is fu is your display name and bar is the name.

[image]